# Do I have to use jupyter notebook/lab/hub for running Dask on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, jupyter, dask, dask-distributed

I am testing dask.distributed for big data and machine learning related things. I've watched videos, read blog pages and tried to understand library documentations. But I am confused. There was always jupyter notebook/lab/hub in every source I found. Do I have to use jupyter notebook/lab/hub in order to run Dask on a Kubernetes cluster? Can't I build a Kubernetes cluster with 2 laptops and run Dask without jupyter related things on them?

Why? Because I want to use my own server (kubernetes cluster) to serve users my own web page (flask in the background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't.  Jupyter is just the most common setup for working with Dask, and JupyterLab has nice extensions so you can visualize task graphs as they are executing.  But for just orchestrating dask workers on kubernetes, I'd have a look at [dask-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/).  That's the library we're using at [Saturn Cloud](https://www.saturncloud.io) to deploy dask for our enterprise customers.

In the docs, these lines should be sufficient to get you started

```
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster

cluster = KubeCluster.from_yaml('worker-spec.yml')
cluster.adapt(minimum=1, maximum=100)  # or dynamically scale based on current
```

It's important to understand that the `KubeCluster` works by attaching a `PeriodicCallback` to the asyncio event loop.  Which means that you definitely want to make sure it doesn't get garbage collected.  You can pass the `cluster` instance directly into the `distributed.client`, Or grab the scheduler address and communicate that way.

Answer (score 2):

I see [no jupyter notebooks](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) here. Jupyter notebooks are convenient for data science folks, but that not a requirement to use tools, you still can `import dask.distributed` into your flask application as any other python package, containerize it and ship it to work in your Kubernetes cluster as service. its all up to you as developer.

Comment: Yes, you are right but [here](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/#dask-kubernetes) and in many other places jupyter related things can be seen. That's why I was confused. And I need to make sure about it. I've already built a cluster of 2 laptops by using the documentation you provided. But this implementation is kinda static. That's why I was looking for a kubernetes implementation without jupyter. So, you are saying it is possible?

Comment: I see no `jupyter` related thing there. I see some kind of deployment with the horizontal autoscale group to whitch you can submit your computation tasks. You can work from jupyter notebook using it as client, but you don't need to. I would suggest following tutorials until you gain enough experience to interact with dask from IDLe or some static file or cli application.  its all up to you.